# Was the mistake in the Falcon's cockpit ever fixed?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, continuity, millennium-falcon

In *A New Hope*, as [this video](https://youtu.be/3YEP5dMXXA0?t=2m47s) points out, the cockpit of the Millennium Falcon has 4 windows on the very front (not counting the round center one) when seen from the exterior, but only 3 when seen from the interior.
[image: outside view]
[image: inside view]
My question is was this always the case, of was it ever fixed in a subsequent film? Essentially, which Star Wars films perpetuated this mistake and which have corrected it (if any)?

---

<sub>I prefer answers have checked each film in which the Falcon's interior and exterior cockpit is seen. In other words, don't just say,
 "well I haven't check any others films, but I just noticed that the Falcon in movie ___ has corrected it". Thanks.</sub>

Comment: How do you know that mullion isn't made of one-way glass/steel (or whatever material ships' cockpits are made of)?

Comment: Shouldn't the research be done in the question? As opposed to asking questions like "Hey I noticed this thing, I know exactly how to answer it but I'm not interested in doing the work, can someone do the work for me?"

Comment: @Edlothiad - I don’t own the digital copies of the Star Wars OT. Also, questions like “how many times has kenobi lied?” get a pass but a simple question like mine gets downvoted? [plays sad harmonica solo]

Comment: @RedCaio yours is probably getting down votes 'cause fanboys

Comment: @RedCaio Take that up with other users, I don't like those question either. I didn't have to open a single digital file of the film. I typed your question into google, opened one of the first links and all the link were provided there for me.

Answer (score 9):

## The mistake was corrected from the interior in later films

## Episode 5

[image]

## Episode 6

[image]

## Episode 7

[image]

## Episode 8

I don't currently have access to data, but it almost certainly is fixed.